# Batch for loop result to variable

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

Hi I'm pretty new in batch programming

I would like to check a few setting through snmpwalk, but to make it more presentable I would like to store the result in to a variable and sort it after

```
For /f "Usebackq Delims=" %%A in (
    "List.txt") do (
SnmpWalk %snmp% -os:.1.0.8802.x.x.x.x -op:.1.0.8802.1.x.x.x.x -q -r:%%A 
"result in to var 1" 
SnmpWalk %snmp% -os:.1.0.8802.x.x.x.x -op:.1.0.8802.1.x.x.x.x -q -r:%%A
"result in to var 2"  
SnmpWalk %snmp% -os:.1.0.8802.x.x.x.x -op:.1.0.8802.1.x.x.x.x -q -r:%%A
"result in to var 3"
SnmpWalk %snmp% -os:.1.0.8802.x.x.x.x -op:.1.0.8802.1.x.x.x.x -q -r:%%A
"result in to var 4"

ehco %var1% "some grafik" %var2%  "some grafik" %Var3%
ehco "some grafik %var4%
```

do i have the wrong approach ?

Comment: You can use a FOR /F command to capture the output of another command.

Comment: Also `ehco` should be `echo`.